# Как активировать + - в поле количества товара?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть такой вот html:

```html
<div class="input-group quantity_goods">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="button_minus">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="button_plus">
</div>
```

Как активировать + - в поле количества товара?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var numCount = document.getElementById('num_count');
var plusBtn = document.getElementById('button_plus');
var minusBtn = document.getElementById('button_minus');
plusBtn.onclick = function() {
  var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
  qty = qty + 1;
  numCount.value = qty;
}
minusBtn.onclick = function() {
  var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
  qty = qty - 1;
  numCount.value = qty;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group quantity_goods">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="button_minus">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="button_plus">
</div>
```

Comment: а когда единица, тоже отнимать будете количество? ))

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы несколько таких же кнопок работали ? Что надо добавить в код?